# How do I address a small /boot?

Tags: boot

I followed the common advice of making /boot on a different partition, and making it a nice and small partition, and all was find for a time.

Fast forward to now, and my partition that has /boot on it that is too small to receive any more updates. How can I safely address this?

Here is my layout according to the lsblk command:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1          8:1    0   256M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2          8:2    0   9.8G  0 part  
│ └─cryptswap 253:0    0   9.8G  0 crypt [SWAP]
└─sda3          8:3    0 921.5G  0 part  /
sdb             8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk  
├─sdb1          8:17   0   128M  0 part  
└─sdb2          8:18   0   3.7T  0 part  
sdc             8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sdc1          8:33   0   100M  0 part  
├─sdc2          8:34   0   128M  0 part  
└─sdc3          8:35   0 465.6G  0 part
```

OS is Pop_OS (an ubuntu derivative)

Contents of /boot:

```
config-4.18.0-18-generic      lost+found
config-4.18.0-25-generic      System.map-4.18.0-18-generic
config-5.0.0-21-generic       System.map-4.18.0-25-generic
grub                          System.map-5.0.0-21-generic
initrd.img-4.18.0-18-generic  vmlinuz-4.18.0-18-generic
initrd.img-4.18.0-25-generic  vmlinuz-4.18.0-25-generic
initrd.img-5.0.0-21-generic   vmlinuz-5.0.0-21-generic
```

Comment: What's your current partition layout?

Comment: I have /boot on one partition, a swap partition, and everything else on another partition.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Post your actual layout, unless you want guess work that may not apply to your case.

Comment: What are the current contents of `/boot` ?

Comment: How many kernels are you saving? What Linux distribution?

Comment: Get rid of some of the older kernels that are there taking up space.

Comment: @ivanivan So just delete anything in there that has a smaller version number than anything else? I'm not really sure which files are the kernals.

Comment: @liljoshu - check your accepted answer :)

Comment: Lol, accepted answer popped up while I was responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your `/boot` partition has enough space for three kernels, so you cannot add a newer kernel now until you delete the oldest.

Your oldest OS install would include the four files with names ending `4.18.0-18-generic`, but rather than just delete them, you should remove them using whatever package tool you use to install them, *e.g.*

```
apt remove linux-image-4.18.0-18-generic
```